# SQL Server dialect with Hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-data

I am using spring data backed by hibernate for my project for the CRUD layer and ORM. I was using H2 first. But when switching to SQL server 2014, I faced the following issue: 
I use the following service:

```
@Query("Select example from Example example where
    example.exampleProperty like CONCAT('%',:param,'%')")
List<Example> findByProductLibe(@Param("param") String param);
```

To get Example object (from example table) using a property. It is working well in H2, but moving to sql server (by switching configuration channel AND Dialect to sql server) i have a BadSqlGrammarException due to the query generated by Hibernate is as follows:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        ex.param1 as param1,
        ex.param2 as param2            
    from
    example ex 
where
    example.exampleProperty like ('%'||?||'%')
```

the problem is with the '|' character, it prints 'Incorrect syntax near '|' '

Here is my database configuration:

```
    database.driver                    = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    database.password                  = 
    database.username                  = 
    hibernate.dialect                  = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy      = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto             = create
    hibernate.generate_statistics      = true
    hibernate.format_sql               = true
    hibernate.show_sql                 = true
```

Thanks for any help or indication.

Comment: Add your Hibernate configuration, please.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with the below code in repo should work.

```
@Query("Select example from Example example where
    example.exampleProperty like %:param%")
List<Example> findByProductLibe(@Param("param") String param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, The problem is finally resolved, I made my *hibernate.dialect* to *org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect* and it generated the following query:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    ex.param1 as param1,
    ex.param2 as param2            
from
example ex 
where example.exampleProperty like ('%'+?+'%')
```

I must have not cleaned and install the project properly.

Thank you.